# Problema com biblioteca PySerial (PYTHON)

Tags: python, arduino, serial

Estou tentando controlar o arduino por um script Python através da biblioteca "pyserial" e "serial". Porém toda vez que executo o código ele dá erro nas primeiras linhas:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)
```

erro retornado:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[...]teste.py", line 3, in <module>
ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'
```

Já dei uma busca no google, mas todas as soluções aplicadas retornam erro. Alguém consegue me ajudar? O arduino está conectado, já carreguei o código nele, mas o problema de fato está na biblioteca.

Já exclui as pastas das bibliotecas e instalei de novo.

Utilizo o PyCharm e o Sublime

Resultado de `print(dir(serial))`:

```
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'WindowsError', 'ZeroDivisionError', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'abs', 'absolute_import', 'all', 'any', 'apply', 'ascii', 'basestring', 'bin', 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'cmp', 'coerce', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'division', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'errors', 'eval', 'execfile', 'exit', 'file', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'generators', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'hooks', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'intern', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'long', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'meta', 'min', 'model', 'native_str', 'nested_scopes', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'print_function', 'properties', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'raw_input', 'reduce', 'reload', 'repr', 'request', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'standard_library', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'sys', 'test', 'tuple', 'type', 'unichr', 'unicode', 'unicode_literals', 'utilities', 'vars', 'with_statement', 'xrange', 'zip']
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Python? Como instalou o módulo *pyserial*? Logo após o `import` qual o resultado de `print(dir(serial))`?

Answer (score 1):

Esse tipo de erro é típico de quando você acha que importou um módulo e importou outro: provavelmente o seu projeto tem um outro arquivo `serial.py`. Esse arquivo deve estar sendo importado no lugar da `serial` que é disponibilizada pelo pyserial.

A solução é renomear seu arquivo que se chama `serial.py` para outra coisa, e o `import serial` vai passar a pegar a biblioteca original.

(Numa nota  a parte, você realmente deveria tentar usar Python 3 aí, se possível - Python 2 é bem antigo já e só vai ter qualquer tipo de suporte por mais 2 anos, além de não incluir nenhuma das novas funcionalidades da linguagem e  ter suporte cada vez menor de bibliotecas terceirizadas.)

Comment: Essa é uma das soluções encontradas no google.

Já havia renomeado meu arquivo para "teste.py" e inclui nele apenas o código acima dito, porém mesmo assim continua dando o erro. Já instalei o Python 3 também para testar, mas não funcionou.

Comment: pela listagem que você dá é como se alguém tivesse jogado o `__builtins__` por cima do `serial`. Procure qualquer arquivo serial.py no seu computador e remova-lo, depois re-instale a pyserial.
Além do dir na pyserial, o que aparece se vocễ imprimir `serial.__file__` ?